# SPARQL Queries on Sub atomic particle ontology

Tags: semantics, sparql, owl, ontology

I am attempting to write SPARQL queries on the ontology periodic.owl
available from 
http://robertdavidstevens.wordpress.com/category/ontologies/

Please provide some sample queries on it that can I use to further build more.
For example a query to retrieve the properties of a particular element

Queries that i build:

```
select distinct ?b where { ?s a ?b. }
```

Now if i want all the details about Antimony5Ion,then i did this:

```
SELECT *
FROM <http://www.co-ode.org/roberts/pto.owl>
WHERE
{
  ?a owl:onProperty ?b.
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to do this yourself yet?  If you can show some queries you've come up with it'll make it easier for others to create answers to your question

Comment: i have posted two queries i can think of

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ?name ?id
FROM <http://www.co-ode.org/roberts/pto.owl>
WHERE 
{ 
  ?id owl:name ?name
}


SELECT ?name
FROM <http://www.co-ode.org/roberts/pto.owl>
ORDER BY ?name
```

Comment: SELECT clause does not match the variables used in the query.